# Changing value of a NSNumber

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to change the value contained in an NSNumber after it is created without making it point to a different NSNumber?

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
num = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1]; // now num points to a different object, which I don't want.  I want it the same object still, but different value.
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

NSNumber is immutable. Actually, it's a subclass of NSValue, and all NSValues are immutable.

Comment: It is a bit odd that there is no NSMutableNumber

Comment: Not really, typically when you'd want a "mutable" number you end up using a primitive. NSNumber is more useful for serialization, being a dictionary key, and things along those lines.

Comment: @MarcCharbonneau there are definitely times when you want a number to be mutable. I just came across one... and ended up just storing my number in an NSMutableString instead (I couldn't be bothered defining my own class just to store a mutable integer in an immutable NSDictionary).

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't change the value of NSNumber.

See, for example, [this post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2004/Jul/msg00092.html).