# How to make an NSNumber negative

Tags: objective-c

I have a `NSNumber` called `myNumber`. Right now, `myNumber = 3`. I want to make it -3. How do I do that, given that the value of `myNumber` will change often?

Comment: I think that if you are going to change it often you should use a primitive, like `int` and make it an NSNumber just when you need to, like for serialization purpose

Comment: You can't. `NSNumber` objects are immutable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing value of a NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071685/changing-value-of-a-nsnumber)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myNumber = @(- myNumber.doubleValue);
```

Or use a primitive, like `NSInteger myNumber` or `CGFloat myNumber`. Performance difference is negligible.